# items in RecyclerView not displaying after filling

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, adapter

after filling the List (correctly filled as my Log shows), the adapter is not displaying the items. I don´t know why.

I read that it´s better to use the special "notify..." methods instead of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`  like `adapter.notifyItemInserted(position)`...i have done (i hope correctly), but it still shows nothing. i hope you can help me...

(The calling from Obejcts and inserting into the list works properly...and i´m not getting any error after running the app, just the Items are not showing)

**DATA Model (User)**

```
public class User {

    public String name;
    public String lastMessage;
    public ParseObject image;


    //Konstruktor
    public User(String name, String lastMessage, ParseObject image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
        this.image = image;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;
    }

    public void setLastMessage(String lastMessage) {
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
    }

    public ParseObject getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(ParseObject image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class UserListAdapter extends SwipeableUltimateViewAdapter<User> {
    public UserListAdapter(List<User> items) {
        super(items);
    }

    //iwas internes
    @Override
    protected int getNormalLayoutResId() {
        return DVHolder.layout;
    }

    //UltimateRecyclerView interaktionen
    @Override
    protected UltimateRecyclerviewViewHolder newViewHolder(final View view) {
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        final DVHolder dvHolder = new DVHolder(view, true);
        dvHolder.swipeLayout.setOnDoubleClickListener(new SwipeLayout.DoubleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoubleClick(SwipeLayout layout, boolean surface) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "DoubleClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        dvHolder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeAt(dvHolder.getPosition());
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deleted " + dvHolder.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        dvHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), ""+dvHolder.getAdapterPosition(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



        return dvHolder;
    }

    @Override //Liste mit Daten füllen
    protected void withBindHolder(UltimateRecyclerviewViewHolder holder, User user, int position) {
        super.withBindHolder(holder, user, position);
        ((DVHolder) holder).name.setText(user.name);
        ((DVHolder) holder).lastMessage.setText(user.lastMessage);
        //Das ParseFile (Image) wird nachher in der UserListActivity per Code geholt und zum ImageView hinzugefügt

    }

    //das so lassen
    @Override
    public DVHolder newFooterHolder(View view) {
        return new DVHolder(view, false);
    }

    //das so lassen
    @Override
    public DVHolder newHeaderHolder(View view) {
        return new DVHolder(view, false);
    }


    //Views etc. anlegen und zuweisen
    public static class DVHolder extends UltimateRecyclerviewViewHolder {
        public static final int layout = R.layout.user_item;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView lastMessage;
        public ImageView userImage;

        public Button deleteButton;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public SwipeLayout swipeLayout;

        public DVHolder(View itemView, boolean bind) {
            super(itemView);
            if (bind) {
                name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
                lastMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastMessageTV);
                userImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userImageIV);

                deleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
                linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

                //diese standardmäßig so lassen, wenn Du swipe willst...
                swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_swipe);
                swipeLayout.setDragEdge(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right);
                swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UserListActivity**

```
public class UserListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private UserListAdapter adapter;
    private List<User> userList;
    private ScrollSmoothLineaerLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    protected UltimateRecyclerView ultimateRecyclerView;

    ParseObject image;

    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSION = 123; //kann jegliche Zahl sein. Wir benutzens halt später


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//      FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//      fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View view) {
//              Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                              .setAction("Action", null).show();
//          }
//      });

        image = null;

        ultimateRecyclerView = (UltimateRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userList_ultimate_recycler_view);

        userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        adapter = new UserListAdapter(userList);
        adapter.setMode(SwipeItemManagerInterface.Mode.Single);
        mLayoutManager = new ScrollSmoothLineaerLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false, 500);
        ultimateRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        ultimateRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // NICHT VERGESSEN DAS MANIFEST DIE PERMISSIONS EINZUTRAGEN  !!! <----------------------------------

        // wenn die Permission NICHT gegeben wurde... und was wir dann machen kommt in diesem Block
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){

                //Hier können wir eintragen, wieso wir eigentlich die Permission brauchen/verlangen
            }else{

                //Permission anfragen
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSION);
            }
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        //Für Join <<<<---------
        // query.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("Name der ID-Spalte hier", "Name der_FOREIGN_KEY-Spalte in der anderen Tabelle", query (der anderen Tabelle hier einfügen); Wir brauchen also query´s von den Tabellen und dann Matchen wir die Keys in den querys. Das kann man mit belieblig vielen Queries machen (also Joinen miteinander)!!!

        if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null){ //Wenn es einen User gibt, der eingeloggt ist.

            query.whereNotEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername()); //Query mit allen Nutzern OHNE mich selber. "username" ist hier die Spalte mit den Nutzer-Namen.
            query.addAscendingOrder("username"); //Aufsteigend sortiert nach usernamen;

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {

                    if(e == null){

                        Log.i("andere User in DB", objects.size()+"");
                        Log.i("Liste vor befüllen", userList.size()+"");

                        if(objects.size() > 0){ // Wenn ich Objekte (Usernamen) habe in meiner Tabelle

                    /*  for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                            usernames.add(objects.get(i).getUsername());
                        }*/

                            // Alternative mit for-each-Schleife (ACHTUNG: Kann sein, dass du noch danach noch arrayadapter.notiyDataSetChanged() aufrufen musst! Teste es einfach mal ohne, ansonsten nach dem befüllen arrayadapter.notiyDataSetChanged(); aufrufen

                            /*for(ParseUser user: objects){
                                userList.add(new User(user.getUsername(), "lastMessage", image)); //TODO: Parsefile später als Image holen
                            }*/

                            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                                userList.add(new User(objects.get(i).getUsername(), "lastMessage", image)); //TODO: Parsefile später als Image holen
                                adapter.notifyItemInserted(i);
                            }

                        }

                        Log.i("Liste NACH befüllen", userList.size()+"");

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if(id == R.id.logout){
            ParseUser.logOut();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

**EDIT: (XML FILES ADDED BELOW)**

**content_user_list.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/content_user_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="ibas.parse.mychat.UserListActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_user_list">

        <com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/userList_ultimate_recycler_view"
            app:recyclerviewEmptyView="@layout/empty_view"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_user_list.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_user_list" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**user_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.swipe.SwipeLayout
            android:id="@id/recyclerview_swipe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/del"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="92dp"
                android:background="#FF5534"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="20">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:text="Delete Item?"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/delete"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:text="DELETE"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:id="@+id/userImageIV"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nameTV"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Teste"
                        android:layout_row="0"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lastMessageTV"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Teste"
                        android:layout_row="0"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.swipe.SwipeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to return the following line
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I have reactivated the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, but didn´t help... 

now I have `adapter.notifyItemInserted(i)` and the `adapter..notifyDataSetChanged();` ...nothing happens.

any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
private List<User> mItems;

public UserListAdapter(List<User> items) {
    super(items);
    mItems = items;
}

....

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}
```

and use 
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: i have added the code, and as before my `notifyData..`. is in my UserListActivity like above.. but no list. it´s still showing nothing.

other idea? what am i doing wrong i wonder...

Comment: Can you add your layout XML?

Comment: i have added my XML Files in my Post (see EDIT).  Thanks.

Comment: It returns the correct ItemCount, but shows no ListItems...what schould i do?